# Does it matter what the font file name is on Windows?

Tags: windows, fonts, truetype

I am migrating a legacy app to a new server after the old server crashed and the new server is missing font files required for the app.  The legacy app has references to the path and font file names i.e. `%WINDIR%/Fonts/schr55w.ttf` not its common name `Century Schoolbook`.

I'm having a hard time finding the required fonts with the same file name.  If I drop a file whose font name is the same as an existing font, will Windows complain or will it accept the new font with a different file name?

This is a Windows 2003 server (ancient tech)

Comment: The problem isn't that the technology is ancient, it's that your "legacy app" was incorrectly written in the first place. Hardcoding a font *file name*? My goodness. I would say that yes, it does matter, but *maybe* Windows does some kind of redirection for the Fonts folder. That's scary place, I try to avoid messing with it.

Comment: Hard to guess how that file name was used.  The only relevant api function I can think of that takes a font file name is AddFontResource/Ex().  Substituting that file shouldn't be much of a problem.  Do post a snippet when you have a question like this.